# Programmatically create Edge browser instance

Tags: vbscript, windows-10, microsoft-edge

Now that Internet Explorer will be discontinued, in Windows 10 Scripting Host (.vbs) how do I create an object to control an Edge instance?

```
Dim oIE
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Comment: The reports of IE's death have been greatly exaggerated.   The only reason they started Edge is to stop having to stay compatible with the myriad of ways IE was used in scripting apps like this one.  Giving it an Automation interface again would completely defeat the point of the project.  So it doesn't have one and never will.

Comment: Can you provide some official references on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the WebDriver for automating testing of the Edge browser.

Blog post here - http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/

Docs on webdriver/selenium are here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt188085(v=vs.85).aspx .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: actually working on a blog post and video about how to spin this up inspired by this question.  will update prob next week.