# Interact with Edge/HTML through vbscript

Tags: html, vbscript, microsoft-edge

I'm new with VBS and I can't find how to interact (basic functions such as clic, write something) with a webpage after having load the URL in Edge.
Here is how I open my webpage for instance

```
dim objShell, strPath1, strAttr1, strAttr2
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strPath1 = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"""
strAttr1 = " -inprivate "
strAttr2 = " http://www.someWebPage.com/ "

objShell.Run strPath1 & strAttr1 & strAttr2
```

I've found many things like that :

```
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.somepage.com/"
```

With this object IE, it seems possible to modify forms, click here and there ... But it only worked with Internet Explorer.

I think I can manage to find the right HTLM piece of code that is useful (at least this is not what I'm looking for right now ^^ ).

Do you have any advise ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Edge browser doesn't support the COM automation interface that used in VBS. If you want to automate Microsoft Edge, you should use [WebDriver](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/).

> To get started using WebDriver, you will need to download a testing framework of your choice along with an appropriate language binding and the MicrosoftWebDriver server.

We usually use Selenium and you could download the language binding in [this page](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/). At the same time, you could download Microsof Edge WebDriver in [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).

Reference link:

[Programmatically create Edge browser instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993588/programmatically-create-edge-browser-instance)

[Will Microsoft Edge support COM automation (InternetExplorer object)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302304/will-microsoft-edge-support-com-automation-internetexplorer-object)

Comment: Thanks for you're answer. Unfortunately I'm working on a computer where I can't install whatever I want (it is provided for my job and I'm not the administrator). 
Is there any other way to do what I'm looking for ?

Comment: I think you have no other choice. In your situation, you can't make it work to automate Edge. You can interact with IE using VBS as a workaround if you want.