# VBA Edge gives unspecific error on ReadyState

Tags: vbscript, microsoft-edge

Ok so I have this script I did some time ago that was working perfectly fine 1-2 years ago on Internet Explorer however now I am on Windows 11 which has only Edge.

Every time I run this script, it hangs on Busy readystate for no reason. Has anything changed in the implementation? Because I am really confused.

```
Set IE = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
strURL = "http://www.website.com/"
IE.navigate strURL
IE.Visible = true
Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4)    
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

Edit just to clarify: This script works just fine all the way to checking the ReadyState. It opens Edge, navigates to URL but then it throws an "Unspecified Error" on the line where it checks the ReadyState.

On Windows 10, it worked perfectly fine with IE.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67179738/interact-with-edge-html-through-vbscript

Comment: @QHarr I will have to disagree with you. The script works up to the first Do While part. It opens Edge to the website however it throws an "Unspecific Error" on that line.

Comment: @QHarr Are you sure you are talking about Edge on Windows 11? IE and Edge are mashed together in Windows 11

Comment: Oh..... I still don't believe it is supported though. Have you read somewhere that it is?

Comment: @QHarr Unfortunately I don't know that much about this as I only have Windows 11 since a few weeks ago. However, IE is non existent on Windows 11 so I assume that Edge will take all the functionality of IE? On Windows 10, this script would open IE, not Edge and would work just fine. I assume something changed in handling the readystate which I am not aware of.

Comment: @SumutiuMarius Edge on Windows 11 is Edge based on the Chromium Project (not the IE engine anymore) so your script would never work as VBScript isn’t supported. Plus VBA and VBScript are two different things, if you are running this script via Excel or another Office product your likely using VBA. If it’s standalone its a VBScript.

Comment: @user692942 So you're saying that they completly dropped support for VBScript in their only browser for Windows 11?

Comment: @SumutiuMarius If it’s Edge then yes, if however it’s the old IE 11 engine which runs from `iexplore.exe` then the answer is no, that should still work and your problems likely stem from the default site security in the IE internet settings. Haven’t got Windows 11 so can’t check but imagine the old engine is still there you just have to look for it.

Comment: @user692942 The old engine is not there. There is no remains of IE whatsoever. I even tried to install IE by downloading it from Microsoft but it doesn't even want to install it. Apparently even Microsoft hates it now. Which is understandable....

Comment: @SumutiuMarius so there’s your answer, if IE doesn’t remain whatsoever then the `InternetExplorer.Application` COM object won’t exist either as it’s powered by the IE engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script presented in the question works correctly in Windows 11 build `22000.348` and above. According to [this article](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2022/03/29/with-3-months-left-before-ie-retirement-new-enhancements-arrive-in-microsoft-edge-for-ie-mode/), Microsoft "inadvertently broke" IE COM automation in Windows 11, but fixed it via an update released in November 2021. As per that same article: "IE COM objects have been restored to their original functionality and will continue to work after the IE11 desktop application is disabled".

Contrary to popular belief, Internet Explorer is still included in Windows 11 and is fully functional for any scripts that depend on it. All that has changed is that IE is not available as a default browser and running iexplore.exe in the usual ways, such as double-clicking, redirects to Edge. The following three line script will continue to launch IE in Windows 11 (and Windows 10 after June 15, 2022):

```
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.Navigate "duckduckgo.com" 'put your URL of choice here
```

Comment: So in other words, it was Microsoft as always...