# gpedit can't open vbscript,but cmd can,what's wrong

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

my system is win10
here is my vbscript to open IE
openIE.vbs

```
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
ws.run "cmd /c start """" /max ""C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe"" """+"https://www.google.com"+"""",vbhide
```

it works in cmd window

```
"C:\Program Files\chromeOpenIE\openIE.vbs"
```

but when I used gpedit to regist it in Register

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
 
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\chromeOpenIE]
@="IE"
"URL Protocol"=""
 
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\chromeOpenIE\DefaultIcon]
@="iexplore.exe,1"
 
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\chromeOpenIE\shell]
 
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\chromeOpenIE\shell\open]
 
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\chromeOpenIE\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\chromeOpenIE\\openIE.vbs\""
```

then use

```
chromeOpenIE://
```

it failed;

Comment: Your `OpenIE.vbs` script won't work on Windows 11 (it will launch Edge) and will also launch Edge on Windows 10 once Microsoft rolls out a patch to "disable" IE. Use [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71949136/15764378) instead.

Comment: you didn't know what I mean

Comment: the script works on win10 which not updated,

Comment: then I don't want to see the cmd window so i used the Wscript.Shell

Comment: My aim is not if the script works,  I want to clear the black cmd window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must run an `Exe` via your protocol handler. You cannot run a batch file or VBScript file directly. Use `Cmd.exe` to run batch files. Use `WScript.exe` or `CScript.exe` to run VBScript files.

Since you want to eliminate the `Cmd` flash, you should eliminate the use of a batch file and just run a VBScript IE launcher via `WScript.exe`. As noted in the comments, your IE launcher is not future proof. Use IE COM automation to launch IE. That works in Windows 11 and will continue to work in Windows 10 regardless of any updates to "disable" IE.

Note that it is bad practice to update HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT directly, as it represents a merged view of HKLM and HKCU entries. You should write your handler registry entries to HKCU, as shown below:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\chromeOpenIE]
@="IE"
"URL Protocol"=""
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\chromeOpenIE\DefaultIcon]
@="iexplore.exe,1"
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\chromeOpenIE\shell]
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\chromeOpenIE\shell\open]
 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\chromeOpenIE\shell\open\command]
@="WScript.exe \"C:\\Program Files\\chromeOpenIE\\openIE.vbs\""
```

And `OpenIE.vbs` should be this code:

```
Set oWSH = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True
oWSH.AppActivate "Internet Explorer"
oIE.Navigate "www.google.com"
oWSH.SendKeys "% "
WScript.Sleep 100
oWSH.SendKeys "x"
```